# Git manage binary files

Tags: git, binaryfiles

It's been a long time I haven't used git for version control and I have a small question.

Back in time I remember it was possible to manage the git diff strategy when adding binary files in version control.

What I want is to add several png files to my project and modify the way git works with them. When I do a git status or a git diff, I want git to prompt those files only if they were touched and do not try to diff with respect to older versions. So that I can add them and push them without killing the system.

Do you know if it's still possible ?

Comment: What is the current behaviour when making `git diff` on a modified image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Description

Use *.gitattributes* to specify how `git` should treat the files.

### Example

Here is a sample from my *.gitattributes* file

```
*       text=auto
*.html  text
*.css   text
*.bat   text eol=crlf
*.sh    text eol=lf
*.jpg   binary
```

### Reference

[git-gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)

Comment: Glad I could help :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use a .gitattributes file to mark those files as binary

```
*.PNG -diff
```

From the [git-scm website](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)

> The simplest way to mark a file as binary is to unset the diff attribute
>   in the .gitattributes file:
>
> *.ps -diff
>
> This will cause Git to generate Binary files differ (or a binary patch, if > binary patches are enabled) instead of a regular diff.

Comment: thank you that was something I haven't heard about. I'll have a look to gitattributes files and what it allow us to do